# Is $(\mathbb{Q};+)$ minimal? What about other divisible groups?

Tags: model-theory

This is a follow up to my previous question, here: [Is the structure $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ minimal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746555/is-the-structure-mathbbr-minimal). I want to know whether the structure $(\mathbb{Q};+)$ is minimal. I conjecture that it is. In fact, I make the stronger conjecture that every divisible abelian group $(G;+)$ is a minimal structure. Is either or both of these conjectures true?

Comment: See the second half of Mark Kamsma's answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three most famous examples of *strongly* minimal structures are:

1. Any infinite set with no extra structure.
2. Any infinite $k$-vector space (for a fixed, but arbitrary, field $k$).
3. Any algebraically closed field.

Now *torsion-free* divisible abelian groups are essentially the same as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces (more precisely, they are *interdefinable* with $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces), so they are strongly minimal. This is what Mark Kamsma explains in the answer to your previous question.

On the other hand, it's certainly not true that every divisible abelian group is minimal. For example, for a fixed prime $p$, consider the group $\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$, the direct sum of countably many copies of the [Prüfer $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group). This group is divisible (since it is a direct sum of divisible groups), but it is not minimal, since the formula $$\underbrace{x+\dots+x}_{p\text{ times}} = 0$$ defines an infinite and coinfinite set.